# FTP Browser plugin for NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, netbeans-plugins

For some time now I am looking for a good FTP plugin for NetBeans. I know it has some basic support but you can only use it with one project and involves downloading everything before you can freely edit/upload stuff..

I was wondering if there was like an FTP browser plugin for NetBeans like in Eclipse or Aptana. You just have the entire FTP server there and can select files when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the [FtpSiteDeployer](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer) plugin. This may meet your needs.

Comment: Not really as integrated as in Eclipse but at least a lot better than the default FTP implementation.. :P Thanks for the tip! Also sorry for late reply..